# How to maintain continuous automatic synchronization with two BLE devices for multiple measurements?

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using A&D BLE BP (Model: A&D_UA-651BLE_31D362) and WS (Model: A&D_UC-352BLE_011E17) to get the latest measurement values from these devices in my iOS app. I am using swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1. I have been able to synchronize, receive and display the data from both devices individually.

But my app requires to setup continuous automatic synchronization with these devices for getting the latest measurement values during multiple measurements without any other synchronization.

Currently my app is performing automatic synchronization with only one device. Actually I cannot understand which section of my implementation I should change to perform automatic synchronization with both devices.

It will be really very appreciated if someone please give me some suggestions regarding how I can extend my implementation for maintaining automatic synchronization with both BLE devices to get latest measurement values during multiple measurements without any other synchronization?

The functions that are related to connect and disconnect these peripherals with the app are given below.

```
    func startScan() {
        if centralManager.state == .poweredOn {
            Logger.log("Starting scan...")
            // Note that some peripherals do not advertise their services
            // until you connect to it so we have to scan for all peripherals.
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        } else {
            Logger.log(level: .warning,
                       "Start scan should not be called until Bluetooth is on.")
        }
    }

    func stopScan() {
        Logger.log("Stopping scan...")
        centralManager.stopScan()
    }

    func getDiscoveredDevices() -> Set<CBPeripheral> {
        return peripherals
    }

    func clearAllDiscoveredDevices() {
        peripherals.removeAll()
    }

    static func getDeviceName(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) -> String {
        if peripheral.name != nil {
            return peripheral.name!
        } else {
            return BTConnector.UNKNOWN_DEVICE_NAME
        }
    }

    static func getPeripheralType(_ deviceName: String) -> PeripheralBTManager.Type? {
        print("getPeripheralType for device:" + deviceName)
        return BTConnector.DEVICE_MAP[deviceName] 
    }

    func getPeripheral(_ deviceName: String) -> CBPeripheral? {
        return peripheralMap[deviceName]
    }

    func setPeripheralManager(_ manager: PeripheralBTManager) {
        btManager = manager
    }

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String : Any],
                        rssi: NSNumber) {
        let deviceName = BTConnector.getDeviceName(peripheral)
        print("discovered peripheral:" + deviceName)
        if deviceName != BTConnector.UNKNOWN_DEVICE_NAME {
            peripherals.insert(peripheral)
            peripheral.delegate = self
            peripheralMap[deviceName] = peripheral
            update()
        }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
            didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
            connectedPeripheral = peripheral
            //connectedPeripheral?.delegate = self // see what this does
            btManager?.didConnect(peripheral)
            Logger.log("Connected \(peripheral).")

            let deviceName = BTConnector.getDeviceName(peripheral)
            let peripheralType = BTConnector.DEVICE_MAP[deviceName]
            if peripheralType is ANDBTManager.Type {
                peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
            }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                            didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                            error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
                Logger.log(level: .error,
                           "Error disconnecting \(peripheral): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let error = error as NSError
                if error.code == BTConnector.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_ERROR_CODE {
                    btManager?.didDisconnect(peripheral)
                    connectedPeripheral = nil
                }
                return
            }
            btManager?.didDisconnect(peripheral)
            connectedPeripheral = nil
            Logger.log("Disconnected \(peripheral).")
        }
func connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
            if peripheralMap[BTConnector.getDeviceName(peripheral)] == nil {
                Logger.log(level: .error,
                           "Tried to connect to a peripheral that does not exist.")
                return
            }
            if connectedPeripheral != nil {
                Logger.log(level: .error,
                           "Overriding connection with \(connectedPeripheral!).")
            }
            stopScan()
            centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            Logger.log("Connecting to \(peripheral)...")
            print("latest value")
        }

        func disconnect() {
            removeConnectionTimer()
            guard let peripheral = connectedPeripheral else {
                print("Peripheral successfully disconnected")
                return

            }
            if peripheralMap[BTConnector.getDeviceName(peripheral)] == nil {
                Logger.log(level: .error,
                           "Tried to disconnect a peripheral that does not exist.")
                return
            }
            if peripheral.state != .connected {
                Logger.log(level: .warning,
                           "Tried to disconnect a non-connected peripheral.")
            }
            centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
            Logger.log("Disconnecting from \(peripheral)...")
        }
```

Comment: You simply need to connect to both devices at the same time and read the required data.  Since you haven't shown any code we can't suggest the changes you need to make.

Comment: Hi Paulw11, in my case I cannot connect both devices at the same time. In my implementation each time I need to go first in the synchronization list to synchronize the device with the app. So if I synchronize BP it will show the result for BP, then to get the WS data again I need to go back to the synchronization list and select the WS device. If I use only one device I do not need to go back again to the synchronization list as it is already synchronized. But if I use two devices, the app is not getting the values unless I am synchronizing each device from the synchronization list.

Comment: Hi Paulw11 I have added the code that are related to connect and disconnect these peripherals with the app. Please check it and inform me if you need any other code.

Comment: Why can't you connect to both devices at the same time.  There is no limitation in Core Bluetooth that prevents this.  If you have structured your app so that there is such a limitation then you need to look at this.

Comment: Hi Paulw11, I have added some codes above, can you please suggest me how I can connect both devices at the same time? What type of changes I should make in didDiscover peripheral section?

Comment: You will need to have two properties to hold the references to your discovered connected peripherals. Once you have discovered a peripheral you can store its `identifier` and use that to retrieve the peripheral and connect to it without needing to discover it again.